inflated custom layout for a Dialog take 2 to 3 seconds before appearing on screen
I have a ViewPager2 with a few fragments. in one of the fragment, I implemented the custom layout for a dialog.
I have a floating button whenever I click it the custom layout shows up. The problem is that it takes too long, sometimes up to 3 seconds to show.
here is the custom layout code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/groceries_edit_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="12dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_grocery_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Add new Item" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:hint="@string/edit_layout_edit_text_hint"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_view_grocery_title">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/item_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/price_text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:hint="@string/price_edit_text_hint"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_text_input_layout">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/price_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:hint="@string/quantity_edit_text_hing"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/price_text_input_layout">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/quantity_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/groceries_type_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/quantity_text_input_layout"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="12dp"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/groceries_type_spinner">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/remove_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/remove_item_button_name"
            android:visibility="gone"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/grocery_save_item_button"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

here is how the code gets inflated (we are in a fragment):
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    private fun setupUI() {
        // inflate the 'Add Item' custom view for the dialog
        val customItemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.groceries_edit_layout, null)
        itemLayoutBinding = GroceriesEditLayoutBinding.bind(customItemView.rootView)

        binding.groceriesFloatingButton.setOnClickListener {
            setupEditDialog()
            itemLayoutBinding.removeButton.visibility = View.GONE
            itemLayoutBinding.textViewGroceryTitle.text = getString(R.string.groceries_add_new_item)
            itemLayoutBinding.itemEditText.setText("")
            itemLayoutBinding.priceEditText.setText("")
            itemLayoutBinding.groceriesTypeSpinner.setSelection(0)
            itemLayoutBinding.quantityEditText.setText("1")
            dialog.create()
            dialog.show()
        }

        //custom layout buttons
        itemLayoutBinding.saveButton.setOnClickListener {
            saveItem()
            showGroceryList()
        }

        itemLayoutBinding.removeButton.setOnClickListener {
            removeItem()
            showGroceryList()
        }

        // spinner adapter
        spinnerAdapter = SpinnerAdapter(requireContext(), SpinnerCategories.Categories.list!!) // !! guarantees list won't be null
        itemLayoutBinding.groceriesTypeSpinner.adapter = spinnerAdapter
    }

when the floating button is clicked!:
private fun setupEditDialog() {
        // detach layout if already attached to a parent
        if(itemLayoutBinding.root.parent != null) {
            val parentView = itemLayoutBinding.root.parent as ViewGroup
            parentView.removeView(itemLayoutBinding.root)
        }

        // androidx.appcompat.R.style.Base_Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_MinWidth
        // com.google.android.material.R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_MaterialComponents_Body_Text
        dialog = Dialog(requireContext(), androidx.appcompat.R.style.Base_Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_MinWidth)
        
        // we have a title in the custom layout
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setCancelable(true)
        dialog.setContentView(itemLayoutBinding.root)
        // when item is clicked on but user tap somewhere else on the screen dismissing the dialog
        dialog.setOnCancelListener {
            dialog.hide()
            recyclerSectionList = null
            recyclerItemPosition = null
        }

    }

I tried AlertDialog, and I tried AlertFragment but both shows up on screen in about the same time (takes 2 to 3 seconds)
I tried with AlertDialog, and I tried AlertFragment but both shows up on screen in about the same time (takes 2 to 3 seconds)
I wish the dialog box would show up on the screen after at most 1 second
